# C quiz Error Spotting

Tags: c

stupid question, but my professor doesn't respond to emails, so I'm asking here.
I'm reviewing for a final right now, and I was going over my midterm exam to study. Now, this is really stupid, because I got this question right 2 months ago. But for the life of me, looking back at it now I can not figure out why this is an error. I'm obviously missing something stupid but I don't know what it is. Please help.

Consider the following program. This program compiles and runs with no error indication, but its output is incorrect.  It has an error.  Which line must be changed in order for the program to produce the correct output?

```
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   /* Find the minimum value in an array of doubles. */
3   double array_min (double x[], int length )
4   {
5       int i;
6       double min = 0.0;
7
8      for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
9      {
10          if (x[i] < min)
11          {
12              min = x[i];
13          }
14      }
15      return min;
16  }
17
18  int main( void )
19  {  
20      double n[] = {12.5, 17.2, 11.4, 8.1};
21      double min;
22  
23      min = array_min (n, 4);
24      printf("The minimum value is %lf\n", min );
25      return 0;
26  }
```

edit: I messed the formatting up, but it's fixed now. I kept the line numbers in for reference, they were part of the question.

Comment: `double min = 0.0;` --> `double min = x[0];`

Comment: Since you *want* the value of `min` at initialization to be overwritten, set it to the maximum value of float. Alternatively, set it to the first element of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Change min to 
min = 1000000.0;
Instead of min = 0.0;
(A large number)
In order to get the min easily, ic the least number in the array is 2 you will not be able to detect it if ths min is already less than it, but if the min is greater it can takd any value dmaller than the huge number in the initialization which is the desired.

Comment: Oh I understand!!!!!!!! Derp. I was looking for some kind of syntax error and it was just a clerical error. I feel stupid.

Comment: No problem, any one could fall in these tiny mistakes, do not forget to vote up for the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Initializing min with a large number (Double.MAX_VALUE) in java for example will guarantee that any number compared to that huge number will be less than it, the code will work fine with no errors and he will not need to start iteration from 1 even.

Comment: @WestonSapusek *"I was looking for some kind of syntax error"* -- you said in the question it compiles and runs. If it has syntax errors then it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
double min = n > 0? x[0] : -1; // '-1' or whatever invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `min` is being initialized to 0: 
`double min = 0`
  
Every input value in `n[]` is **greater** than 0.
  You will need to change the initialization value of `min` in order for this function to work.
You have **2** options see below:

1. You can change the initialization value of min to be the maximum value a double can hold (assuming 64 bits) which is approximately:  **1.7976931348623157 × 10<sup>308</sup>**
   `min = 1.7976931331348623157E308;`
2. Or you can initialize `min` to be the value of `x[0]` like so:
   `min = x[0];`

I would sooner choose option 2 since it is comparing actual values from the array and not using an approximation.

Comment: The size of `double` is 80bits instead of 64bits.